# Select a string ending at the first instance of character in Regular Expressions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Say I have the following string:

```
pos/S881.LMG1810.QE009562.mzML
```

And wish to select the beginning from that string:

```
pos/S881.
```

I can use the following regex expression to get the start of the string (^), then any character (.), any number of time (*), ending with a decimal point (\.)

```
^.*\.
```

However this terminates at the last decimal in the string and thus gives me:

```
pos/S881.LMG1810.QE009562.
```

How do I terminate the selection at the first decimal point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround (`(?<=\\.)`) to match the characters that succeed after the `.` and remove those with `trimws`

```
trimws(str1, whitespace = "(?<=\\.).*")
[1] "pos/S881."
```

---

Or extract the characters from the start (`^`) of the string that are not a `.` (`[^.]+`) followed by a dot (metacharacter, thus escaped)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "^[^.]+\\.")
[1] "pos/S881."
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "pos/S881.LMG1810.QE009562.mzML"
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively just use `sub()`:

```
s <- 'pos/S881.LMG1810.QE009562.mzML'
sub("\\..*", ".", s)
# [1] "pos/S881."
```

- `\\..*` - Match a literal dot followed by 0+ characters.

Answer (score 4):

We could use `strsplit`:

With `strsplit` function and indexing we extract the desired part of the string:

```
strsplit(x, "\\.")[[1]][1]
```

```
[1] "pos/S881"
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepting @akrun answer for their quick response but found that the "?" modifier makes "*" non greedy in my original expression as written.

```
stringr::str_extract("pos/S881.LMG1810.QE009562.mzML", "^.*?\\.")
[1] "pos/S881."
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `regexp` approach is using `sub` along with the pattern `"(^.*?\\.).*"` , e.g.,

```
> sub("(^.*?\\.).*", "\\1", "pos/S881.LMG1810.QE009562.mzML")
[1] "pos/S881."
```